# Как правильно: проживает три человека или проживают три человека?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно: проживает три человека или проживают три человека?

Answer (score 6):

В зависимости от контекста (абстрактно о количестве людей говорят или о конкретных личностях), могут быть основания для согласования грамм. числа либо с числительным, либо с существительным.

```
На столь малой жилплощади проживает три человека, что нарушает санитарные нормы.


В квартире проживают три человека: Дарья К., Фёкла К. и Демьян К.
```

Answer (score 1):

Это вопрос согласования ([см.](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)). В данном случае следует использовать сказуемое во множественном числе.