# Входит или входят

Tags: орфография

В перечень входит 250 организаций: предприятия, фирмы и арендаторы.

Comment: Здесь было уже много подобных вопросов. Например ["В: Как правильно: проживает три человека или проживают три человека?"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418894/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0?r=SearchResults&s=1|47.6218)

Comment: Ещё: ["В: Как правильно согласовать число глагола?"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453752/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0?r=SearchResults&s=4|25.2381)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таких вопросов было множество, например ["подходит два" или "подходят два"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457350)

Корректные варианты:

> В перечень входит множество из/в 250 организаций.
>
> В перечень входит 250 организаций как единое множество.
>
> В перечень входит 250, а не 251 организация.

> В перечень входит около 250 организаций.

Хотя я сейчас ознакомился с предыдущими ответами, и похоже что оба варианта из вопроса "официально" допустимы. Просто мне на аналогичный вопрос сказали, что допустим только один вариант.